# How can i install external pinax projects?

Tags: django, pinax

I try to deal with poor documentation of Pinax.

I found this project

```
https://github.com/pinax/pinax-multiblog-project
```

what i want is that install it. I normally install a project called account  but here i have to install from git . How can i do that in Pinax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Edit:

It turns out the new way of using projects is to just copy the folder and rename it.

### Usage instructions:

So to use the multiblog project you would do

Copy the multiblog inside the cloned repo to a new location and rename it to the name you would like to use for your project. Then install the requirements via pip and follow the rest of the steps for setting up a django project

#### OSX/Linux:

```
cd ~/src
git clone https://github.com/pinax/pinax-multiblog-project
cp -r ~/src/pinax-project-admin ~/Sites/new_project
cd ~/Sites/new_project"
pip install -r requirements.txt
python manage.py syncdb
```

---

I too have been trying to accomplish the same thing. So far I found this commit
https://github.com/nrb/pinax/blob/476d2398c48cc444eb2338c12090f0cebad46961/docs/starterprojects.txt

Relevant section on begins on line 160 near the end

```
External Starter Projects
=========================

The Pinax ``setup_project`` command can also use starter projects built by third     parties. 
These can either be plain directory structures, or they may be a git/hg pip editable.

To install a starter project from an external source, simply pass the file path or git/hg 
URL to the ``-b`` option::

pinax-admin setup_project -b git+git://github.com/user/project.git#egg=project my_new_project
```

However all the pinax projects I have come across don't seem to include an egg to use

eg:

1. https://github.com/pinax/pinax-multiblog-project
2. https://github.com/pinax/pinax-project-account

I need to use Django 1.4 for my project but the included account base project in both Pinax 0.9a2 and 0.9b1-dev10 use Django 1.3.

I am guessing the external project integration is something we will have to wait for in the Pinax 1.0 release.

Comment: yeap i installed after some trials but directories are downloaded incompletely